# About Flex, Bison and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am trying to run my self-made compiler for a simplified java language, however I always end up with a segmentation fault. 
The goal is to build an abstract syntax tree. I also tried to debug with valgrind, but it looks like the tool has some problems with bison and flex on my PC. Please help me.

The Lexfile:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abst.h"
#include "yacc.tab.h"
int yylineno;
int column = 0;
int nesting_comments = 0;
int max_comment_level = 0;
int total_comments_number = 0;

void count() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; yytext[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(yytext[i] == '\n')
        column = 0;
        else if(yytext[i] == '\t')
        column += 8 - (column % 8);
        else
        column++;
    }
    //printf("%s", yytext);     Uncomment this Line for printing the input stream
}

void yyerror(char const *s);

%}

DIGIT       [0-9]
LETTER      [a-zA-Z]
WHITESPACE  [ \t\r]

VINT         {DIGIT}+
VFLOAT       {VINT}+"."{DIGIT}*
VDOUBLE      {VFLOAT}E{VINT}
VSTRING      \".*\"

COMMENT1    "//".*
%x          COMMENT2
COMMENT3    "/""*"([^{"*""/"}])*"*""/"

REL_OP      "<"|"<="|"=="|"=>"|">"|"&&"|"||"|"&"|"|"|"!="
ADD_OP       "+"|"-"|"%"
MUL_OP       "*"|"/"
UNARY_OP     "++"|"--"
ASSIGN_OP    "+="|"-="|"*="|"/="|"%="
TYPE        "boolean"|"int"|"float"|"double"

ID {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*

%%
"if"                            { count(); return IF; }
"else"                          { count(); return ELSE; }
"while"                         { count(); return WHILE; }
"for"                           { count(); return FOR; }
"read"                          { count(); return READ; }
"write"                         { count(); return WRITE; }
"final"                         { count(); return FINAL; }

{VINT}                          { count(); yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return IVALUE; }
{VFLOAT}|{VDOUBLE}              { count(); yylval.fval = atof(yytext); return FVALUE; }
{VSTRING}                       { count(); yylval.identifier = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
"true"                          { count(); return TRUE; }
"false"                         { count(); return FALSE; }
"boolean"                       { count(); return BOOLEAN; }
"int"                           { count(); return INT; }
"float"                         { count(); return FLOAT; }
"double"                        { count(); return DOUBLE; }


{ID}                            { count(); yylval.identifier = strdup(yytext); return IDENT; }
{REL_OP}                        { count(); yylval.ival = getEnum(yytext); return RELOP; }
{ADD_OP}                        { count(); yylval.ival = getEnum(yytext); return ADDOP; }
{MUL_OP}                        { count(); yylval.ival = getEnum(yytext); return MULOP; }
{UNARY_OP}                      { count(); yylval.ival = getEnum(yytext); return UNARYOP; }

"="                             { count(); return '='; }
"!"                             { count(); return '!'; }
"("                             { count(); return '('; }
")"                             { count(); return ')'; }
"["                             { count(); return '['; }
"]"                             { count(); return ']'; }
"{"                             { count(); return '{'; }
"}"                             { count(); return '}'; }
","                             { count(); return ','; }
";"                             { count(); return ';'; }

{COMMENT1}  {
    total_comments_number++;
    count();
}

"(*"  {
    total_comments_number++;
    BEGIN(COMMENT2);
    printf("(* [BEGIN NESTED %d]\n", nesting_comments++);
    count();
}

<COMMENT2>[^*()]*   {
    printf("%s", yytext);  /* Eat other characters */
    count();
}
<COMMENT2>"(*"   {
    printf("(* [BEGIN NESTED %d]\n", nesting_comments);
    if(++nesting_comments > max_comment_level) {
        max_comment_level = nesting_comments;
    }
    count();
}
<COMMENT2>"*)"   {
    printf("\n*) [END NESTED %d]", --nesting_comments);
    if (nesting_comments == 0){
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
    }
    count();
}
<COMMENT2>[*()] {
    printf("%s", yytext);  /* Eat the other characters if it is not a comment delimiter */
    count();
}

{COMMENT3}  {
    total_comments_number++;
    count();
}
{WHITESPACE}+                     { count(); }
\n                                { count(); yylineno++; }
.                                 { yyerror("Lex"); }

%%
```

The Yaccfile:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include "abst.h"

    extern char *yytext;
    extern int yylineno;
    extern FILE *yyin;
    extern int column;

    extern int nesting_comments;
    extern int max_comment_level;
    extern int total_comments_number;

    int yylex(void);
    //int yydebug=1;

    node *root;

    void yyerror (char const *s){
        fprintf (stderr, "%s Error at line %d:%d\n", s, yylineno, column);
        fprintf (stderr, "Text was: %s\n", yytext);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
%}

%union {
    char *identifier;
    int ival;
    float fval;

    struct _node *node;
}

%type <identifier> IDENT STRING
%type <ival> IVALUE MULOP RELOP ADDOP UNARYOP
%type <fval> FVALUE
%type <node> program compStmt varDecList varListType type varList ident identArray stmtList
%type <node> statement assignStmt ifStmt elsePart whileStmt forStmt ioStmt ioCall paramList
%type <node> expr simpleExpr term factor mulop addop relop

%token IF ELSE WHILE FOR WRITE READ FINAL
%token IVALUE FVALUE TRUE FALSE STRING
%token BOOLEAN INT FLOAT DOUBLE
%token IDENT

%right UNARYOP '!' '='
%left MULOP ADDOP RELOP
%left '[' ']' '(' ')'

%start program

%%
program
:   compStmt                        { $$ = $1; root = $1;}
;

compStmt
:   '{' varDecList stmtList '}'     { $$ = new_node(COMP_STMT, (node*[]){ $2, $3, NULL });}
;


varDecList
:   varListType varDecList          { $$ = new_node(DECLARATION, (node*[]){ $1, $2, NULL }); }
|
;

varListType
:   type varList                    { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST_TYPE, (node*[]){ $1, $2, NULL }); }
|   FINAL type varList              { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST_TYPE, (node*[]){ new_string_node(TYPE, "final") , $2, $3, NULL }); }
;

type
:   BOOLEAN                         { $$ = new_string_node(TYPE, "boolean"); }
|   INT                             { $$ = new_string_node(TYPE, "int"); }
|   FLOAT                           { $$ = new_string_node(TYPE, "float"); }
|   DOUBLE                          { $$ = new_string_node(TYPE, "double"); }
;

varList
:   ident ',' varList               { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
|   ident ';'                       { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
|   ident '=' expr ';'              { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
;

ident
:   IDENT                           { $$ = new_string_node(VAR, $1); }
|   identArray '[' simpleExpr ']'   { $$ = new_node(ARRAY, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
;

identArray
:   IDENT                           { $$ = new_string_node(VAR, $1); }
;

stmtList
:   statement stmtList              { $$ = new_node(STATEMENT_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, $2, NULL }); }
|   statement                       { $$ = new_node(STATEMENT_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
;

statement
:   assignStmt ';'                  { $$ = $1; }
|   compStmt                        { $$ = $1; }
|   ifStmt                          { $$ = $1; }
|   whileStmt                       { $$ = $1; }
|   forStmt                         { $$ = $1; }
|   ioStmt                          { $$ = $1; }
;

assignStmt
:   ident '=' expr                  { $$ = new_node(ASSIGN_STMT, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
|   ident UNARYOP                   { $$ = new_node(ASSIGN_STMT, (node*[]){ $1, new_int_node(OP, $2), NULL }); }
;

ifStmt
:   IF '(' expr ')' statement elsePart {
        if($6->type != NONE){
            $$ = new_node(IF_STMT, (node*[]){ $3, $5, $6, NULL });
        }
        else {
            $$ = new_node(IF_STMT, (node*[]){ $3, $5, NULL });
        }
    }
;

elsePart
:   ELSE statement                  { $$ = $2; }
|                                   { $$ = new_none(); }
;

whileStmt
:   WHILE '(' expr ')' statement    { $$ = new_node(WHILE_STMT, (node*[]){ $3, $5, NULL }); }
;

forStmt
:   FOR '(' assignStmt ';' expr ';' assignStmt ')' statement {
                                      $$ = new_node(FOR_STMT, (node*[]){ $3, $5, $7, $9, NULL });
    }
;

ioStmt
:   ioCall '(' paramList ')' ';'    { $$ = new_node(IOFUNC, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
;

ioCall
:   READ                            { $$ = new_int_node(IOFUNCCALL, 0); }
|   WRITE                           { $$ = new_int_node(IOFUNCCALL, 1); }
;

paramList
:   ident ',' paramList             { $$ = new_node(PARAM_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, $3, NULL }); }
|   STRING ',' paramList            { $$ = new_node(PARAM_LIST, (node*[]){ new_string_node(STRING_CONST, $1), $3, NULL }); }
|   ident                           { $$ = new_node(PARAM_LIST, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
|   STRING                          { $$ = new_string_node(STRING_CONST, $1); }
;

expr
:   simpleExpr relop simpleExpr     { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, $2, $3, NULL }); }
|   simpleExpr                      { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
;

simpleExpr
:   term addop simpleExpr           { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, $2 ,$3, NULL }); }
|   term                            { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
;

term
:   factor mulop term               { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, $2, $3, NULL }); }
|   factor                          { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
;

factor
:   IVALUE                          { $$ = new_int_node(INT_CONST, $1); }
|   FVALUE                          { $$ = new_float_node(REAL_CONST, $1); }
|   TRUE                            { $$ = new_int_node(BOOL_CONST, 1); }
|   FALSE                           { $$ = new_int_node(BOOL_CONST, 0); }
|   ident                           { $$ = $1; }
|   '!' factor                      { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $2, NULL }); }
|   '-' factor                      { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $2, NULL }); }
|   '(' expr ')'                    { $$ = new_node(EXPR, (node*[]){ $2, NULL }); }
;

mulop
:   MULOP                           { $$ = new_int_node(OP, $1); }
;

addop
:   ADDOP                           { $$ = new_int_node(OP, $1); }
;

relop
:   RELOP                           { $$ = new_int_node(OP, $1); }
;

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    if ( argc > 1 )
        yyin = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    else
        yyin = stdin;
    yyparse();
    printf("\nCOMMENT-ANALYSIS:\n");
    printf("Total number of comments: %d\n", total_comments_number);
    printf("Maximum nested comment level: %d\n", max_comment_level);
    printf("\n");

    printNode(root);

    return 0;
}
```

The Header in which I decleared some structs and enums:

```
#ifndef AST_TYPES_H
#define AST_TYPES_H

typedef enum {
    COMP_STMT = 0,
    ASSIGN,
    ASSIGN_STMT,
    IF_STMT,
    FOR_STMT,
    WHILE_STMT,
    STATEMENT,
    STATEMENT_LIST,
    CONST,
    VAR,
    ARRAY,
    VAR_LIST,
    TYPE,
    EXPR,
    SIMPLE_EXPR,
    INT_CONST,
    REAL_CONST,
    BOOL_CONST,
    STRING_CONST,
    IDENTIFIER,
    OP,
    IOFUNC,
    IOFUNCCALL,
    PARAM_LIST,
    DECLARATION,
    VAR_LIST_TYPE,
    NONE,
} node_type;

typedef enum {
    PLUS = 0,
    MINUS,
    MUL,
    DIV,
    MOD,
    LT,
    LE,
    GT,
    GE,
    EQ,
    NE,
    AND,
    OR,
    PLUSPLUS,
    MINUSMINUS,
    NOT,
} operator;

typedef union _node_value{
    int iValue; /*integer, true, false, compOp, addOp, mulOp */
    float fValue; /*number*/
    char* identifier; /*identifier*/
    /* list of BNF right-hand side symbols of nonterminal type */
    struct _node **body;
} node_value;

typedef struct _node {
    node_type type;
    int size;
    node_value value;
} node;

void printNode(node *the_node);
operator getEnum(char *value);
char *printEnum(node_type type);
node* new_none();
node* new_int_node(node_type type, int value);
node* new_float_node(node_type type, float value);
node* new_string_node(node_type type, char *value);
node* new_node(node_type type, node **nodes);

#endif //AST_TYPES_H
```

The c-file which implements the headerfunctions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "abst.h"

node* new_none(){
    node *the_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (the_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not allocated memory for node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    the_node->type = NONE;
    the_node->size = 0;
    return the_node;
}

operator getEnum(char *value){
    switch (value[0]) {
        case '+':
            if(value[1] == '+')
                return PLUSPLUS;
            else
                return PLUS;
        case '-':
            if(value[1] == '-')
                return MINUSMINUS;
            else
                return MINUS;
        case '*':
            return MUL;
        case '/':
            return DIV;
        case '%':
            return MOD;
        case '<':
            if(value[1] == '=')
                return LE;
            else
                return LT;
        case '>':
            if(value[1] == '=')
                return GE;
            else
                return GT;
        case '=':
            if(value[1] == '!')
                return NE;
            else
                return EQ;
        case '&':
            return AND;
        case '|':
            return OR;
        case '!':
            return NOT;
    }
    return -1;
}

node* new_int_node(node_type type, int value){
    node *the_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (the_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not allocated memory for node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    the_node->type = type;
    the_node->size = 0;

    switch(type){
            case INT_CONST:
            case OP:
            case BOOL_CONST:
            case IOFUNCCALL:
            the_node->value.iValue = value;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf (stderr, "Node-Type %s is wrong for int value %d\n", printEnum(type), value);
    }
    return the_node;
}

node* new_float_node(node_type type, float value){
    node *the_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (the_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not allocated memory for node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    the_node->type = type;
    the_node->size = 0;

    if(type == REAL_CONST)
        the_node->value.fValue = value;
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "Node-Type %s is wrong for float value %f\n", printEnum(type), value);
    return the_node;
}

node* new_string_node(node_type type, char* value){
    node *the_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (the_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not allocated memory for node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    the_node->type = type;
    the_node->size = 0;

    switch(type){
        case VAR:
        case STRING_CONST:
        case TYPE:
            the_node->value.identifier = value;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf (stderr, "Node-Type %s is wrong for String %s\n", printEnum(type), value);
    }
    return the_node;
}

node* new_node(node_type type, node **nodes){
    int counter = 0;
    while(nodes[counter] != NULL){
        counter++;
        if(counter > 4){
            fprintf (stderr, "Could not find NULL for %s\n", printEnum(type));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    node *the_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    the_node->type = type;
/*
    switch(type){
        case STATEMENT_LIST:
        case DECLARATION:
        case VAR_LIST:
            if(counter == 2 && nodes[1]->type != EXPR){
                int size = nodes[1]->size + 1;
                the_node->size = size;

                the_node->value.body = malloc(size*sizeof(node*));
                the_node->value.body[0] = nodes[0];

                for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                    the_node->value.body[i] = nodes[1]->value.body[i-1];
                }
                return the_node;
            }
    }
   */ 
    the_node->value.body = (node**) malloc(counter*sizeof(node*));
    the_node->size = counter;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        the_node->value.body[i] = nodes[i];
    }
    return the_node;
}

void printNode(node *the_node){
    if(the_node->type > NONE){
        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong Type %d\n", the_node->type);
        return;
    }

    printEnum(the_node->type);
    switch(the_node->type){
        case INT_CONST:
            printf("%s with INT-value: %d\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.iValue);
            break;
        case REAL_CONST:
            printf("%s with FLOAT-value: %f\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.fValue);
            break;
        case BOOL_CONST:
            printf("%s with BOOL-value: %d\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.iValue);
            break;
        case VAR:
            printf("%s with Identifier: %s\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.identifier);
            break;
        case OP:
            printf("%s with Operation: %d\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.iValue);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s with size %d\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->size);
            for (int i = 0; i < the_node->size; i++) {
                printNode(the_node->value.body[i]);
            }
    }
}

char *printEnum(node_type type){
    switch (type) {
        case COMP_STMT:
            return "COMP_STMT";
        case ASSIGN:
            return "ASSIGN";
        case ASSIGN_STMT:
            return "ASSIGN_STMT";
        case IF_STMT:
            return "IF_STMT";
        case FOR_STMT:
            return "FOR_STMT";
        case WHILE_STMT:
            return "WHILE_STMT";
        case STATEMENT:
            return "STATEMENT";
        case STATEMENT_LIST:
            return "STATEMENT_LIST";
        case CONST:
            return "CONST";
        case VAR:
            return "VAR";
        case ARRAY:
            return "ARRAY";
        case VAR_LIST:
            return "VAR_LIST";
        case TYPE:
            return "TYPE";
        case EXPR:
            return "EXPR";
        case INT_CONST:
            return "INT_CONST";
        case REAL_CONST:
            return "REAL_CONST";
        case BOOL_CONST:
            return "BOOL_CONST";
        case STRING_CONST:
            return "STRING_CONST";
        case IDENTIFIER:
            return "IDENTIFIER";
        case OP:
            return "OP";
        case IOFUNC:
            return "IOFUNC";
        case IOFUNCCALL:
            return "IOFUNCCALL";
        case PARAM_LIST:
            return "PARAM_LIST";
        case DECLARATION:
            return "DECLARATION";
        case VAR_LIST_TYPE:
            return "VAR_LIST_TYPE";
        case NONE:
            return "NONE";
        default:
            printf("\nUNDEFINED: %d\n", type);
            return "UNDEFINED";
    }
}
```

I compile the program like this:

```
bison -d --debug --verbose yacc.y
flex lex.l
gcc yacc.tab.c lex.yy.c abst.c -std=c11 -Wall -o run -ll -g
./run < sample.java
```

This is the sample-file for the java grammar, which should be compiled:

```
/* This program that implements a few well-known algorithms */

{ int x, y, z;
  final int n = 10;
  int a[n];

  // greatest common divisor
  { read(x, y);
    while(x * y != 0)
      if(x > y)
        x = x - y;
      else y = y - x;
    if(x == 0)
      write("gcd = ", y);
    else write("gcd = ", x);
  }

  // factorial calculation
  { read(x);
    y = 1;
    for(z = 2; z <= x; z++)
      y = y * z;
    write(x, " != ", y);
  }


  // prime number verification
  { int k;
    boolean prime;
    read(x);
    k = 2;
    prime = true;
    while((k < x/2) && prime) {
      if(x % k == 0)
        prime = false;
      k++;
    }
    write(x, " is prime is ",  prime);
  }

  // maximum array element
  { int i, max;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      read(a[i]);
    max = a[0];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if(max > a[i])
        max = a[i];
    write("max = ", max);
  }


  // bubble sort
  { boolean k;
    float r;
    int i;
    k = true;
    while(k) {
      k = false;
      for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]) {
          b = a[i];
          a[i] = a[i+1];
          a[i+1] = b;
          k = true;
        }
    }
    write("sorted array: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      write(a[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: caveat: I do not know lex, and yacc, and it has be a couple of decades since I worked with java:   That said, this line: `if ( argc > 0 )` is not correct.  The `argc` will ALWAYS be greater than 0 due to the first entry in the `argv[]` will be the path/name used to invoke the program.  Suggest: `if( argc > 1 )`

Comment: Thx for looking at my code. And indeed this is a bad error, i made. However it still does not change the problem with the segmentation fault. You dont have to know much about bison or flex, since this error could also simply be a wrong use of malloc... The java program is only an example-code which should be compiled by my program.

Comment: Aside: your GCD code needs some `{`braces`}` and the algorithm is exceedingly inefficient - as would be a division algorithm implemented with the `-` operator. For example, your algorithm takes 132 loops to calculate `gcd(2000, 15)` whereas one which uses the modulus operator `%` takes 1 loop (2 operations as it's a `while` loop).

Comment: @Aside this is only a examplecode which should be get compiled to get an abstract sytax tree. The java program will never really run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of running the program directly from the command line, do:

```
gdb run
```

then at the `(gdb)` prompt do

```
run < sample.java
```

which will produce output ending with something like:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a66c36 in vfprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

telling you that the problem is in something passed to `printf`.  From here, use the `bt` command to get a stack backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a66c36 in vfprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a6f299 in printf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000404b14 in printNode (the_node=0x60c870) at abst.c:178
#3  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60c930) at abst.c:186
#4  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60c970) at abst.c:186
#5  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60ca70) at abst.c:186
#6  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60d190) at abst.c:186
#7  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60d6d0) at abst.c:186
#8  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60d710) at abst.c:186
#9  0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x60d750) at abst.c:186
#10 0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x613500) at abst.c:186
#11 0x0000000000404b94 in printNode (the_node=0x613540) at abst.c:186
#12 0x00000000004024a7 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0a8) at yacc.y:208
```

to see how you got into this state.  Now use the `up` command twice (to go two frames "up" in the stack trace -- down on the list above), and you're at:

```
#2  0x0000000000404b14 in printNode (the_node=0x60c870) at abst.c:178
178             printf("%s with Identifier: %s\n", printEnum(the_node->type), the_node->value.identifier);
```

from here you can print the values of things with the `p` command:

```
(gdb) p the_node->value
$1 = {
  iValue = 2, 
  fValue = 2.80259693e-45, 
  identifier = 0x2 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>, 
  body = 0x2
}
```

which tells you what the (immediate) problem is -- you're accessing `identifier` from the union when it actually holds what is probably an `iValue`, so you're passing a garbage pointer to `printf` which causes the crash.

For more information on gdb commands, try the `help` command...

Comment: After a long searching around (in my code) I found out, that bison does not work with yylval. Instead I have to use the $-Symbols and set the right type. Your answer helped me to find this mistake. I think now should everything work. I will report back tomorrow.

Comment: I found now all failures in my code. I accept your answer, because you even run my code on your computer and helped me finding all errors with some gdb commands I did not know. I will later come back and write a summary of all mistakes I made.

Comment: This is a great explanation on how to use gdb to debug. Thanks to you, now I'll only touch gdb with a 5-foot pole (it was 15 feet before reading your post)

Answer (score 3):

That's really a lot of code, too much for a simple visual inspection. You should probably try executing the program with a debugger, enable bison tracing, and/or write some test code to verify that your node-building functions work as expected. (I'd go with all three.)

One thing which does leap out is that you have a number of rules like this:

```
BOOLEAN                   { $$ = new_node(TYPE, (node*[]){ $1, NULL }); }
```

which assume that there is some semantic value associated with a terminal token representing a simple keyword. However, the flex rule which returns the keyword token type

```
"boolean"                 { count(); return BOOLEAN; }
```

does not set `yylval`. In fact, *no flex rule ever sets yylval*, so it will always be NULL. (It's a global variable, so it will be zero-initialized.)

So if the `node*` used to construct the new `type` node in the bison rule above is ever dereferenced, you'll get a segfault. I didn't trace through the code to see if it is ever dereferenced, so that may or may not explain your issue.

Comment: Thank god an answer :D I will defenitly try this tomorrow :) I will report back.

Comment: I edited the code, so that it includs yylval. But the segmentation fault remains. I am quit sure there is still a porblem with some nodes, which didn't get initialized.  @rici, can you again take a look at my code and give response? I don't know what i can improve.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't rely on `yytext` anywhere in the .y file. As *yacc* is an LALR(1) parser, it's already gone. You need to copy it to a piece of dynamic memory in the lexer, and assign it to a member of the `yylval` union:

   ```
   yylval.text = strdup(yytext);
   ```
2. As you are writing C++, you should not use node-type variables. You should create a *family* of node classes, that inherit from `node`, and equipment them with constructors and virtual methods to do whatever they need to do in each specific case.

Comment: I updated the code like you and rici said. The code remains in C style, so that I can continue using gcc to compile my files. There have to be some big errors left. I would be happy if also you can again take a look at the code.

Comment: You could make life a lot simpler by not redoing things that *yacc* already does for you. You don't need to define your own token Enum. It's already there in y.tab.h. You don't need one for operators either. All theses rules for single character operators can be replaced by `. return yytext[0];`, and you then use them directly in the grammar as `'+', '-'`, etc. Makes everything much more readable and there is much less code, which ditto. You'll have to run this under a debugger and tell us where the failure occurs.

Comment: This is really a nice improvement! I will change my code.